# At which wilderness level am I unable to teleport?

Tags: runescape

I heard that you can't use teleports past a certain wilderness level and I would like to know after which level that happens.

And is that level different for the various teleport options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [the wiki](http://services.runescape.com/m=rswiki/en/Wilderness#Teleport_Restrictions) says,

> Up to level 30, enchanted dragonstone jewellery, the Pharaoh's Sceptre and grand seed pods from the Gnome Restaurant may be used, and a ring of life will save you if activated. Other forms of teleportation can be used up to level 20.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the Evolution of Combat update the new lodestones can be teleported to in the wilderness. However once you pass level 25 you can't use this form of teleportation. Dueling rings can be used but not past 20 Wilde.